# JavaScript functions give errors when loaded via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dom

**EDIT:**
OK, I believe I've found a way around the issue using the info posted by @ManseUK along with @Johan's comment. As a n00b I can't answer my own question but I've added an explanation below the question in case it helps anyone else out.

> I am re-writing part of an e-commerce solution which was written by
>   another development team some years ago. In the new version, we are
>   experimenting with shortening the user journey using Ajax but doing so
>   gives JavaScript errors and causes some functions to fail. Dev URL is
>   here:
>
> http://cognition.thelightbulb.co.uk/type-18/general-purpose-lamps-and-bulbs/craftlight-daylight
>
> The errors appear once the dropdowns have been selected and the
>   product displays.
>
> The errors are displaying most notably in IE7:
>
> ```
> Error: 'frm.qty' is null or not an object
> Error: 'qty.value' is null or not an object
> ```
>
> I believe this is where the problem is coming from:
>
> ```
> var frm = document.frmOrder; 
> var qty = frm.qty;
> ```
>
> In the lines above, `frmOrder` is the name of the form and `qty` is
>   the name of the input for product quantity.
>
> Compare that to http://cognition.thelightbulb.co.uk/product-54 where
>   the product loads without the Ajax selection process and you'll see
>   that the functions work correctly.
>
> I suspect that the problem is to do with the fact that `var frm =
>   document.frmOrder;` is not working due to the way it relates to the
>   DOM when loaded with Ajax.
>
> I am using `innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText` as the Ajax method. Is
>   there an alternative way to define `var frm` so that it will function
>   properly when loaded with Ajax?

**EDIT:**
Using the info posted by @ManseUK along with @Johan's comment, I added another argument to `CheckMinQty(minorder)` so that it now looks like this...

`function CheckMinQty(minorder,qty)`

...where `qty` is passed to the function on an `onclick` event as `document.forms['frmOrder'].qty.value`

I then moved the whole function out into a separate .js file. It's maybe not the best approach but it still feels tidier for the Ajax call to just return workable HTML which `CheckMinQty` can use rather than bringing in a whole load of `<script>` and then trying to run it.

Thanks for all the suggestions and I'd welcome any comments about the approach/solution outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
var frm = document.frmOrder;
```

to this

```
var frm = document.forms['frmOrder'];
```

That will give you a handle to the form

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ManseUK but I'm still getting `Error: 'frm.qty' is null or not an object` when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

document.frmOrder refers to the element with id frmOrder on the page, which happens to be the form on this page. Just try to get the correct form-element as the variable there.

Comment: Thanks @Johan, the script works fine here: http://cognition.thelightbulb.co.uk/product-54 so I think I have the right form element. It's just a case of making it work with Ajax

Comment: Ok, I see you first set the frm-variable (when the page just finished loading), and execute the functions when things are clicked. Don't set the frm-variable too early, just get it when needed. Not the best solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Though the Manse's solution might work, use a more sensible way and assign an id to the form and since you're using jQuery anyway, retrieve the form with `var frm = $(#formid);` Not only is it easier to write, it's much more easier to read by you and everybody else.

Answer (score 0):

When loading script via AJAX, you don't have `DOMReady` event anymore. In other words, when you want to execute your script on AJAX load, you should use **self-invoked functions**. 
Wrap your ajax-loaded script inside a function like this:

```
(function(){
    // Do what you want to do here.
})();
```

See if that solves the problem?

Comment: Thanks @Saeed, that seems to have prevented any errors when the page loads. 'CheckMinQty(minorder)' is still failing though. I guess this is because it uses `qty.value`. Should 'function CheckMinQty(minorder)' sit outside the self-invoked function?